# How to validate US zip code by country and state using Google's Geocoding component filtering?

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoding-api, zipcode

I am using Google's Geocoding API using the component filtering.

To validate the zip code in a specific country I use the following call for example:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:94301|country:USA

I want to add another component to indicate the state. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geocoder#GeocoderComponentRestrictions.administrativeArea) I can do it using the "administrativeArea".

**I couldn't get it to work.**
For example, calling the API with the zip code 94301 and state "Arizona" should return with no values, while the state "California" should return the relevant address.

I tried: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:94301|country:USA|administrativeArea=Arizona

Answer (score 0):

You are using `administrativeArea=Arizona` in components filtering. Please note that web service should use `administrative_area=Arizona` according to the documentation.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering

> The following components may be used to influence results, but will not be enforced:

> - route matches the long or short name of a route.

- locality matches against locality and sublocality types.
- **administrative_area** matches all the administrative_area levels.

When I execute the following request

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=administrative_area%3AArizona%7Cpostal_code%3A94301%7Ccountry%3AUS&key=MY_API_KEY`

I get the response

```
{
  "results":[    
  ],
  "status":"ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

You can also see this in Geocoder tool:

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#in_administrative_area%3DArizona%26in_postal_code%3D94301%26in_country%3DUS%26options%3Dtrue

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D%26in_country%3DUS%26in_administrative_area%3DCalifornia%26in_postal_code%3D94301

I hope this helps!